# Finding Palindromes in a large text

Tags: python, palindrome

So we got a text with about 600000 characters, that is without "space" and fullstops. I've removed those from the text. Now i gotta find all palindromes of length greater than 7 in that text, and I need a little help of how to get that done.

I have already tried one thing, but that was way too slow.

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits

s = open("pg1150.txt").read()
s = s.lower()
s = "".join([c for c in s if c in ascii_letters or c in digits])
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i + 6, len(s) + 1):
        t = s[i:j]
        if t == t[::-1]: 
            print(t)
```

The input text is: http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1150/pg1150.txt

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some of your input and your expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: A string of length n is a valid palindrome candidate only if one specific substring of length n-2 is also a palindrome. How can you utilize this?

Comment: printing something every time you find it (rather than accumulating them) won't help with speed (Though this isn't the main issue. @Ria has hinted that your algorithm itself can be radically imporved)

Comment: @Ria yea i figure, also the code doesnt need to look further than 2 ahead. Say that it didnt find any of length 10 or 11 if doesn't need to look for any at length ≥12.

Comment: I assume a palindrome can start or end in the middle of a word, and punctuation does not matter? BTW, the input text seems to be blocked in some countries. Could you post a small (!) excert (!) directly in the question itself, for reference?

Comment: @tobias_k yeah that's right. The words in the text doesnt matter that is why I removed punctuation and upper case letters

Answer (score 2):

Note the if a string s<sub>0</sub>...s<sub>n</sub> is a palindrome, then s<sub>1</sub>...s<sub>n-1</sub> is also a palindrome

In short, iterate through your file searching every valid palindrome of length 7 and length 8 (thanks to @tobias_k that noted that otherwise you'll only get the odd palindromes), but instead of printing it, save its index to a separate list.

```py
for i in range(len(s) - 8):
    t1 = s[i:i+7]
    t2 = s[i:i+8]

    if t1 == t1[::-1]: 
        index_table.append(i)
    if t2 == t2[::-1]: 
        index_table.append(i)

#You have to ensure that the only substring of length 7 that goes unchecked isn't a palindrome
if s[-7:] == s[-7:][::-1]:
    index_table.append(len(s) - 7)
```

Now that you have your "base" for all future palindromes, it's easy to use the recursive relationship mentioned earlier to construct all other palindromes.

```py
for i in index_table:
    n = 0
    while (s[i-n] == s[i+6+n]):
        print(s[i-n:i+6+n])
```

Comment: Do the same for palindromes of length 8, or you will only get those of odd length.

Comment: It just keeps repeating the same 6 letter word. I get the first code segment, but when i append it to a list, how can i make sure, that it only print the same word once. And can i sort them by length?

Comment: The list only stores unique indices. If you want unique words, you can simply use a hashmap. If efficiency isn't an issue, just store every palindrome to a new list and filter it by calling set()